# Change the color to the clicked element

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to change the color of the clicked div element. If I change the color with  the color is transferred to each next click div.
How to click on the div element to change the color of that div element. First click on some div and then change color?

```
<html>
<head>
<style> 
html, body {
    overflow: display;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

#some_id1{
  width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}

#some_id2{
  width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}

#some_id3{
  width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}

#some_id4{
  width: 50px;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="color" id="divbackgroundcolor" onchange="myFunction()">
<div id="some_id1"></div>
<div id="some_id2"></div>
<div id="some_id3"></div>
<div id="some_id4"></div>
<div id="some_id5"></div>

<script>

var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= divCount; i += 1) {
    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        var x = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
        document.getElementById(this.id).style.backgroundColor = x;
    };
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so first, I don't understand why are you using id on each div, while you are having the same style for each. better do it with class

Secondly, I have looked it up a little, and what I discovered people do, is just hide the color picker (`input`) and trigger it on click.

In your piece of code, it would look something like this:

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divCount = div.length;
var clickedDivId

for (var i = 0; i < divCount; i += 1) {
    div[i].onclick = function(e) {
        clickedDivId = this.id
        document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").click()
    };
}

function colorChange(){
  var x = document.getElementById("divbackgroundcolor").value;
  document.getElementById(clickedDivId).style.backgroundColor = x;
}
```

```css
html, body {
  overflow: display;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
}
#divbackgroundcolor {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
.some_style {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="divbackgroundcolor" onchange="colorChange()">
<div class="some_style" id="some_id1"></div>
<div class="some_style" id="some_id2"></div>
<div class="some_style" id="some_id3"></div>
<div class="some_style" id="some_id4"></div>
<div class="some_style" id="some_id5"></div>
```

Notice that what I did is saved the id of the div I clicked on, so I could tell on which div I have clicked.
Hope that is the answer you are looking for.

Good luck.

Comment: Eden Eliel figured it out.
What I need is to keep <input type = "color"> visible.
NO <input type = "color"> should appear immediately after clicking on div.
1. First click on the div (red color does not change)
2. Click on <input type = "color"> to change the color.

Comment: Well, you can take what I did and make it visible :). Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Your example have only to mistakes:

In HTML remove the "onclick" in your "input"

And in JS your "for" loop use "i < divCount"

Change just those lines and will work!

Comment: Maybe I did not explain my question well.
First I want to click on the div, the div color does not change. Change only with <input type = "color">
By clicking on div I want to change only that div.

Comment: still your requirement seems confusing, can you explain in some other way. Also what you need to do exactly.

Comment: When I click on a div black color appears immediately. First I want to click on the div, after the click, the color div should remain red until I change it to another color.